# Java for loop with a while loop inside

Tags: java

I didn't understand why in this code that calculates the powers of 2, the e is decremented inside the while loop:

```
public class Power {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        int e;
        int result;

        for (int i=0; i< 10; i++) {
            result = 1;
            e = i;
            while (e > 0) {
                result *= 2;
                e--;
            }
            System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);   
        }
    }
}
```

If I run without the e-- the code only executes the first one. It only works with the e--.

Comment: This is the perfect case for an IDE debugger like the one in Eclipse for instance.

Comment: Can you work it out by hand, at least for the first few values of `i`?

Comment: i=0, while loop is false, result =1;  i=1, while loop true: 1*2  but then why e--? The i will return to 0 then?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom correct its good practice for looping, debug manually by hand

Comment: I indented your code correctly. Once indented correctly, it's suddenly much easier to understand the code.

Comment: Now I get it, it's only for the while loop, like when the i=2 then e=2, so the while to stop need to be equal to 0, then it will run once and decrement, run again and decrement until it get 0 and stops, and so on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand what is going on, consider the inner loop in isolation from its outer loop:

```
e = someNUmber;
while (e > 0) {
    result *= 2;
    e--;
}
```

The loop stops when `e` reaches zero. That's why there needs to be *some* operation inside the loop body to change the value of `e` to get it closer to zero.

Your loop is equivalent to this `for` loop:

```
for (int e = someNumber ; e > 0 ; e--) {
    result *= 2;
}
```

The value of `e` is your loop counter. It controls the number of iterations of the inner loop, ensuring that it executes exactly `i` times.

Answer (score 1):

It is because to calculate the power of 2 to **i** then you have to multiply 2, **i** times. So each time **i**(the required power of 2) is assigned to e and is decremented so that you multiply by **i** times.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at what happens for the first few values of `i`, it becomes clear:

#### i = 0

```
result = 1; // e = 0, result = 1
```

#### i = 1

```
result = 1;  // e = 1
result *= 2; // e = 0, result = 2
```

#### i = 2

```
result = 1;  // e = 2
result *= 2; // e = 1, result = 2
result *= 2; // e = 0, result = 4
```

#### i = 3

```
result = 1;  // e = 3
result *= 2; // e = 2, result = 2
result *= 2; // e = 1, result = 4
result *= 2; // e = 0, result = 8
```

The inner loop is ensuring that the result gets multiplied by the number 2 `i` times.

An (arguably clearer) alternative for the inner loop and the extra `e` variable would be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    result *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I run without the e-- the code only executes the first one.

Actually in this case your program stucks in infinite loop

```
while (e > 0) {
    result *= 2;
}
```

You see only one result because on first iteration of for loop `e` equals `0` so program doesn't enter into while loop

Answer (score 0):

`e--` is existed to prevent an infinite loop, removing it will result in infinite `while` loop in the **second** iteration of `for` loop since `e` will never change and thus it'll never become zero, and you'll never break out of the loop to reach the `System.out.println` statement or to even to go the next iteration in the `for` loop.